# Split the row into multiple columns in MySql

Tags: mysql, split

I have a table in mysql database.In the table one column is storing the values with comma separation.

Now i want to split the row into multiple rows where the comma symbol has occurred.

Example:

```
id          column1

----------------------------

1          a,b,c
2          c,f
3          s,d,f,g
4          p
5          k,h,s
```

like so on ..............

with this table data i want to show like below.

```
id          column1
----------------------------
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          c
2          f
3          s
3          d
3          f
3          g
4          p
5          k
5          h
5          s
```

so on...............

could any one  provide me the solution how to get my required output through the mysql query.

In Sql i used split function but if i used the same function in mysql it is not working.

Thanks In Advance,
Phani kumar.

Comment: Please provide some code. Point us toward the part where you tried what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You are starting from the wrong place. You should never store comma delimited values. That said, you're moving in the right direction, so here's one way of getting from a to b...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_bad_table;

CREATE TABLE my_bad_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,column1 VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_bad_table VALUES
(1,'a,b,c'),
(2,'c,f'),
(3,'s,d,f,g'),
(4,'p'),
(5,'k,h,s');

SELECT * FROM my_bad_table;
+----+---------+
| id | column1 |
+----+---------+
|  1 | a,b,c   |
|  2 | c,f     |
|  3 | s,d,f,g |
|  4 | p       |
|  5 | k,h,s   |
+----+---------+

SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

CREATE TABLE my_good_table AS
SELECT DISTINCT id
              , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1,',',i+1),',',-1) x 
           FROM my_bad_table
              , ints 
          ORDER 
             BY id
              , x;

ALTER TABLE my_good_table ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,x);

SELECT * FROM my_good_table;
+----+---+
| id | x |
+----+---+
|  1 | a |
|  1 | b |
|  1 | c |
|  2 | c |
|  2 | f |
|  3 | d |
|  3 | f |
|  3 | g |
|  3 | s |
|  4 | p |
|  5 | h |
|  5 | k |
|  5 | s |
+----+---+
```